# MySQL error #1064 on create function

Tags: mysql

Here is my code:

```
create function getten() returns integer
begin
return 10;
end
```

giving me error message:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I have no idea what the '' is all about. Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, SQL code is written in big letters. 
Second, please remember indention.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getten()
  RETURNS INTEGER
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN 10;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

should work like this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION getten()
  RETURNS INTEGER
  BEGIN
  RETURN 10;
  END;
 $$

DELIMITER ;

SELECT getten();
+----------+
| getten() |
+----------+
|       10 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need to define the type of return in function

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    FUNCTION `getten`()
    RETURNS INTEGER

    BEGIN
RETURN 10;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And after creation you can use it like

```
SELECT `getten`()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have only one statement to be executed, you need not use `begin` - `end`.

```
create function getten() returns integer return 10;
```

Otherwise you need default syntax to bind multiple statements within `begin` - `end` block.

And to restrict the database engine interpret the statements immediately when it finds a default statement close instruction by a `semi colon`, we use custom `delimiter`.

```
delimiter //

create function getten() returns integer
begin 
  return 10; 
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

It would be a good practice to follow using the block type body rather than using an inline single statement.

Comment: You should always use them, just for clarity in my opinion.
But i guess, that is user preference:)

Answer (score 0):

All your answers were great, but only worked after I added 'deterministic' before 'begin'.

Thanks a lot.